# How set correct value into anonymous function?

Tags: javascript

I have datagrid in my webapp, and I have to initialize all buttons that are there.

I tried this.

```js
function initButtons() {
 var i = 0;
 var playBtn, markBtn;
 for (;; i++) {
  playBtn = document.getElementById('musicCloudForm:musicDataGrid:' + i
    + ':playMusicButton');
  if (playBtn == null)
   break;
  playMusicButton[i] = playBtn;
  playMusicButton[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    playPauseGridAudio(i);
  }, false);
  markBtn = document.getElementById('musicCloudForm:musicDataGrid:' + i
    + ':markMusicButton');
  markMusicButton[i] = markBtn;
 }
 alert('Number of buttons - ' + i);
}
```

Where `playPauseGridAudio`:

```js
function playPauseGridAudio(number) {
 alert('Button number ' + number);
 //another code
}
```

In this case **if I press any button**(I have 3 buttons in this case) **I get next message:

`Button number 3`**

I think problem is here:
`playMusicButton[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
                 playPauseGridAudio(i);}, false);`

Comment: You are right about where the problem is :)

Comment: This looks like the job for a `while` loop, any reason you are using a `for`?

Comment: And on a more related note, how about putting in your addEventListener `alert(this.id)`?

Comment: @jcuenod unfortunately, type of loop doesn't solve my problem :)   
`alert(this.id)` give me different result for each button, but why value of **i** is the same for each button?